# Merging JSON arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

How can I merge objects A and B in PHP resulting in C?

Object A

```
{
    "folders": {
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "folders": {
                {
                    "name": "foo"
                },
                {
                    "name": "bar"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "bar"
        }
    }
}
```

Object B

```
{
    "folders": {
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "folders": {
                {
                    "name": "foobar"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "foobar",
            "folders": {
                {
                    "name": "foo"
                },
                {
                    "name": "bar"
                },
                {
                    "name": "foobar"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Object C (expected result)

```
{
    "folders": {
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "folders": {
                {
                    "name": "foo"
                },
                {
                    "name": "bar"
                },
                {
                    "name": "foobar"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "bar"
        },
        {
            "name": "foobar",
            "folders": {
                {
                    "name": "foo"
                },
                {
                    "name": "bar"
                },
                {
                    "name": "foobar"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I use function array_merge_recursive the keys "name" will be turned into an array with multiple values equals to the original string.

Comment: Object C wont work, duplication of array keys in the 'folders'

Comment: i think wrong json formate

Comment: You'll probably have to write your own merge function.NB: That isn't correct JSON syntax. For JSON arrays you have to use `[...]`.

Comment: Your examples are not valid - not as PHP array and not as JSON string. I can guess what you want and could probably fix your "strings" into valid JSON and use json_decode() to get an array, to get something to work on. Please fix this in your question. --- What have you tried so far? Show us a code example you worked on using these pieces of example data.